# SSRS expression, IIf statement with three conditions

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a filter on a Group Properties, CaseNO, that when the three conditions are present to return that row and those three items:

Here is the IIF Statement:

=IIF((Fields!ExtConnID.Value="2") AND (Fields!ExtConnID.Value="200") AND
(Fields!ExtConnID.Value="2040"),True,False)

But, I get no hits/data. Can someone with clear eyes and mind, help me out?

Thanks,
JER

Comment: your expression will only return true if ExtConnID is 2 AND 200 AND 2040 which obviously it cannot be, it can only be 1 value. If you want to return true when any of the 3 conditions is true then change your `AND`s to `OR`s

Comment: Alan, thanks for your reply. But, I only want a return when ALL three are true. A CaseNo can have all three of those and if it does return that row. Thanks,

Comment: ExtConnID can only exist once per row or scope (rowgroup, column group etc), SSRS will evaluate the expression as a single value, so it cannot be all three at the same time. If you edit your question and show a sample of data and expected results then maybe somebody can help. I suspect you might have to flag matching CaseNo's in your dataset query and filter based on that but without seeing your data/results it's hard to help.